# Dialog box error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to add an image in dialog box. When I click on button it adds the image to the dialog box the first time, but when I click the button second time the image is not displayed in dialog box. What is the problem?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Dialog functionality</title>
<link
    href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
.ui-widget-header,.ui-state-default,ui-button {
    background: #b9cd6d;
    border: 1px solid #b9cd6d;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
    $(function() {

//Button function
$("#button").click(function(){

        $('<div id="dialog" title="title">Imageselected</div>').dialog({
            resizable:false,
            buttons: {"Enrol": function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                "CancelEnrol": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
$('#dialog').append('<img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-1-6584893165273088-res.png"/><br/>').append($(this).html());
    });
  });       

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="button"  value="Reset"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What *is* in the dialog box the second time?  What is the resulting markup that gets created?  When you step through the code in a debugger, is the behavior any different on the second button click?

Comment: What's `choice(true)` and `choice(false)`?

Comment: Can you provide a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: I copied your html and ran it in both IE and FF. It looks ok for me. Which Browser you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens because you are creating the dialog on every click and after it you are making the `.append` 
You can make the append before create the dialog:

```
$(function() {

//Button function
$("#button").click(function(){

        $('<div id="dialog" title="title">Imageselected</div>').append('<img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-1-6584893165273088-res.png"/><br/>').append($(this).html()).dialog({
            resizable:false,
            buttons: {"Enrol": function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                "CancelEnrol": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nfhLjkv7/

If you does not need create the dialog on every click , just open the dialog on the click function